# Custom equations' names

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing

Do you know how I can call a reference to an equation using `\ref` or `\eqref` and obtain the `(name of the equation)` instead of the standard counter?

Comment: What to you mean, "name of the equation"? How is this name defined?

Comment: I think what Abramo means is to write something like `\eqname{eqn:Stokes}` to produce something like `Stokes equation` in the document (instead of `\eqref{eqn:Stokes}` which produces `(1)`). Abramo, am I right?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use the `amsmath` package you can do

```
\begin{equation}
  \tag{*}
  \int_{\partial\Omega} \omega = \int_\Omega d\omega
  \label{eqn:Stokes}
\end{equation}

By \eqref{eqn:Stokes} ...
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: @Matthew: I'd always recommend using `\eqref{eqn:Stokes}` instead of `(\ref{eqn:Stokes})`. By the way, there's a closing brace missing ...

Comment: Yeah, this is what i was searching for, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with 'eqnarray'

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray`, it is horrible. Use `amsmath`'s `align` and friends instead.

Comment: @Hendrik: For some reason I never got into the habit of `\eqref` although I agree it's better.  Thanks also for pointing out my missing brace (and to Khaled I guess for fixing it).

Comment: @Hendrik: I like using the `fncylab` package and then `\labelformat{equation}{(#1)}` so that I can just write `\ref{eqn:Stokes}`.  Though then it requires more work NOT to get the parentheses.

Comment: @Ryan: Good tip for those who really _type_ the `\eqref`, and I can't think of a situation where I wouldn't want the parentheses. I won't use it since for me, `\eqref{}` is `Alt+R` and, e.g., `Strg+Alt+t` gives `Theorem~\ref{}`.

Answer (score 18):

The `\tag{your name here}` construct can be used inside `\begin{equation} .. \end{equation}` and the amsmath `\begin..end{align}` constructs in order to give equations visible names instead of numbers:

```
\begin{equation}
  \tag{Super Fun Equation}
  y = 3x
\end{equation}
```

Labels can then be used to refer to names in references:

```
\begin{equation}
  \tag{Super Fun Equation}
  y = 3x
  \label{eqn:super}
\end{equation}
...
See \eqref{eqn:super} for an awesome equation % See Super Fun Equation for ...
```

Comment: I seem to be getting (??) instead of the name. Are there any dependencies I should add?