# How do I give an equation a name instead of a number?

Tags: equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom equations' names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/custom-equations-names)

I'd like to label a couple of equations by **name**, right-aligned, where the (number) would normally appear in the document: how do I do this?

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/custom-equations-names

Comment: Okay, turns out \tag is what I was looking for... I saw the other question, but it wasn't clear from the answer there exactly what the solution was --- it all seemed to be about references rather than display names.